# Image class not found in intervention plugin

Tags: laravel

Image class not found in intervention plugin. are there any body help me how can I install this plugin step by step??  I was read already a lot thing about installation this package. but it does not work. and I cant successfull to install. please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the top :

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;
```

Comment: If it really healped then don't forget to mark this answer as accepted https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3287